Django Prefetch object with generic relation
As stated in the documentation:

class Prefetch(lookup, queryset=None, to_attr=None)

The Prefetch() object can be used to control the operation of prefetch_related().
The queryset argument supplies a base QuerySet for the given lookup

For example, it can be used to specify the columns from the related object to SELECT, by using only():
Author.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("hometown", City.objects.only(["name"]))

However, when prefetching the objects related through a generic relation, what model should be passed to the queryset param of Prefetch? I can't see any references to that on the docs nor SO.
Something like:
Prefetch("foo", GenericRelation.objects.only(["title"]))

